# Can I get requester's local time (or offset) from Actions On Google?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

I'm building on the Actions On Google API using API.ai. In order to fulfil one of my actions I need to know the user's location and local time.

I have been able to successfully ask for and receive back the user's location.

However, I cannot see any way of getting the user's local time or timezone offset. Is there a way to do this?

(I realise that I could use the location to find out the offset but that would require another API call or use of another library, which I'd rather avoid.)

Thanks in advance.

**-- Update --**

As per Leon's answer below and as of 18th Jan 2017 this info isn't currently provided by the API. In order to get the required info I requested permission for the user's precise location, which returns lat and lng. I then used the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org)  timezone API to get the timezone offset.

Comment: Would it be an option to use `@sys.date-time` as an Entity in the request?

Comment: Mmm, that could be an option to get it but as I understand it the user would first have to be encouraged to say a date and time that would be matched by the entity. I don't think the entity slot would be filled without this... Unless you know differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device's timezone isn't provided to the action yet.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Leon.
It seems to me that it'd be a useful and not particularly privacy-invasive piece of info to provide so hopefully it'll be provided soon and I'll be able to add an addendum here.
In the meantime, I guess that is the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Whilst the timezone isn't included natively yet to my knowledge. You can use location permission alongside libraries to get the local time  dynamically.

The libraries I have used here are momentTz and timezone. The latter gets the timezone interpolated from lat/long supplied by location permission. The resolved timezone is then used to convert the standard time in UTC which momentTz provides natively to the local time sought.

```
const startTz = momentTz(); //Returns standard UTC time, independent of locality
const timestamp = 1402629305; // Any random timestamp will work, it wouldn't unnecessarily impede your results 

timezone.data(latitudeValue, longitudeValue, timestamp, function(err, tz) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

var zoneHolder = tz.raw_response.timeZoneId; //Appropriate timezone is returned here based on latitudeValue and longitudeValue passed
const localTime = startTz.tz(zoneHolder).format('LLL'); //local time which you seek;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks similar to what I ended up doing except that I do the timzone interpolation via the Geonames API.
Does the timezone library you reference do the interpolation offline? Or does it also require a call out to a 3rd party API?
Can you please add a link to the timezone library as from a quick Google search, I'm not sure which you are using.

Comment: You are welcome. I am not certain the interpolation is offline..., In my case though, I am running other requests online simultaneously whenever I utilise the call, so it might be difficult to exactly tell. See the link here: (https://npmjs.com/package/node-google-timezone)